# jQuery iFrame Modal Return Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I applied the modal function I found in this **[article](http://deseloper.org/read/2008/04/a-simple-modal/)**. It is a jQuery modal that puts the `source file` in an `<iframe>` and display as modal. Now, the problem is that I need to return to **value** to the background page from the modal after the user selected an item.

Here is some jQuery code: *(This is were the page is loaded)*

```
var openMyModal = function(source)
{
    modalWindow.windowId = "myModal";
    modalWindow.width = 480;
    modalWindow.height = 405;
    modalWindow.content = "<iframe width='480' height='405' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' allowtransparency='true' src='" + source + "'></iframe>";
    modalWindow.open();
};
```

Posible code in Modal:

```
<select name="selItem">
     <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
     <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
     <option value="item3">Item 3</option>
     <option value="item4">Item 4</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="btnSel" name="btnSel" value="Select" />
```

There is a `button` in the modal display which when clicked, it will pass the **value** to an `input text` back to the background page then remove the modal.

How can I achieve this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to add click listener on the button of the model after it opens. here is some code:

```
modalWindow.open(function()
{
    //callback
    $('#btnSel').on('click', function()
    {
         //do what you need here.
    });
});
```

**Note:**
Make sure there is some way to run a callback function like I suggested.

from the documentation you can add your logic in the `open` option:

```
var modalWindow = {
    ....
    open:function()
    {
        //your stuff - click listener 
    }
};
```